# How to include js file in the php file which has been called from ajax hit?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

1st file - Making ajax request by get method to 2nd file which is php.

2nd file- Then including the 3rd file which is also a php file but has both few lines of html as well as javascript.

3rd file - In this php file I am including a js file as shown below:

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="abcd.js"></script> 
</head></html>
```

But I am unable to include this abcd.js file. Mainly I am including this file to call a function from 3rd php file which has been defined in abcd.js.

Comment: And what is your real question?

Comment: Maybe `How to dynamically load javascript with ajax and php?` :)

Comment: echo this `<script type="text/javascript" src="abcd.js"></script>` in the third php and you'll get this in ajax

Comment: My question is how to include abcd.js in my 3rd php file? As for now I am unable to do that